# Cucumber breaks single xpath in 'Scenario Outline Example' into multiple arguments

Tags: xpath, arguments, cucumber

QUESTION: how have you AVOIDed or FIXed Scenario Guidelines that scramble a single XPATH into 3 or more step parameters?

```
@wip
 Scenario Outline: Browse to Target URL having multiple specified WebElements
    Given Using browser "<theBrowser>" 
    When targetURL "<targetURL>" is entered
    Then Expected Page "<targetURL>" is loaded 
    And  Loaded Page displays webelements with locator "<locatorID>" 
 Examples:  
 | theBrowser |   targetURL       |       locatorID                   | 
 |  chrome    | www.qaweb.net/    |  //*[@id="loginwithajaxwidget-5"] | 
 |  firefox   | www.ganbatte.net/ |  //*[@id="loginwithajaxwidget-2"] |
```

Problem(s)
 1. The tests are skipped as UNdefined 
 2. the xpath is broken into three (3) parameters arg1~arg4

```
@Then("^Loaded Page displays webelements with locator \"([^\"]*)\"loginwithajaxwidget-(\\d+)\"([^\"]*)\" having innerText \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void loaded_Page_displays_webelements_with_locator_loginwithajaxwidget(String arg1, int arg2, String arg3) throws Throwable
```

I am using "Offical Eclipse Plugin for Cucumber"

Comment: This may be due to the double quotes in the xpath. Try changing them to single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Locators should not be included in cucumber examples that should all be done under the hood. Think about an end-user reading your scenarios, they would have no idea what a locator is. Instead the locator should be in your page object and the step should be a business step.

Comment: Thanks: probably a good policy  in most cases, yet still a parsing bug with a dubious side affect of enforcing one universal policy on individual instances, that assumes all implementations are with large organizations with non technical stake holders, thereby requiring dividing data that could be more efficiently called from one source. For now I will follow your advice to avoid the limitation/bug and use a unique label or Test Plan cross reference for the locator that the programmer will lookup from a data file.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber generates snippets using very simple rules. They are often useful, but should always be treated as suggestions only.

In this case, edit the suggested snippet (or write your own step definition) to match your requirement. For example:

```
@Then("^Loaded Page displays webelements with locator \"(.*)\"$")
public void loaded_Page_displays_webelements_with_locator_loginwithajaxwidget(String xpath) throws Throwable
```